# date-picker for safari and dynamic created element on PHP form?

Tags: php, dynamic, safari, datepicker, element

how can i add datepicker supporting safari and on multiple class in the php form?

I have a PHP form on which have some element  class name. How can i create Date picker for all elenment and also dynamically created elenment?

Comment: <input type='date' name='startDT' >

Comment: @jeff - that doesn't work for dynamically created objects.  There is nothing to trigger creating a datepicker on a new item added to the DOM, just by using a class.

Answer (score 0):

typically you'll want do something like this

```
 $('.date-picker').hover(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('hasDatepicker')){
             $(this).addClass('hasDatepicker');
             $(this).datepicker();
        }
 });
```

This way the first hover creates the datepicker, assigns the `hasDatepicker` class that acts like a switch for any subsequent hover events.

Then when you create/add new items, you don't get hit by creating the datepicker  tell a user actually wants to use it.  Now you can just add

```
 <input type="text" class="date-picker" />
```

All you want, at any time you want.

Comment: Thank you .. I need little more help I have class which as already names so i want number of classes to be using date-picker.  Actually there are file element which clones and becomes total 15 classes each of different class name. So i want to know how to add date-picker for all the 15 classes